# how to change the style of a richfaces 3.3.4 progressbar

Tags: css, richfaces

I am trying to change the style of a RichFaces 3.3.4 progressBar so that it doesn't have animation and it would also be nice to change the color of the bar. I have tried the css class selector If nothing else I need to have the animation disabled. I have tried to get this to work for about a week, so I have been looking things up, but nothing seems to work for 3.3.4. I can't upgrade to 4.3 though due to project constraints.

Comment: Can you post your code snippet that include the progress bar and what you have tried?

Comment: Ok, I will do that when I get back to the office. I have done multiple writes and rewrites though, so I won't be able to show everything that I have tried. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Sorry for never coming back to this, got busy with other things. I ended up just using an HTML progress bar that was updated with calls to a JavaScript function. (calls were made by an a4j-poll)